# How to make the textformfield with drop down list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-edittext, dropdown

I am making an application where I have to write my location in text form field and from server it fetches the data and show us the similar words related to the words in drop down list and I can choose from that list or can write a complete new location in text form field, if it is not present in that drop down list. How can I achieve that in flutter?

Note: I don't want to use google places API right now in my project but will do that definitely in future. Right now I can store my locations in my server.

Comment: You need to deal with HTTP requests and Futures, also Streams and some state management methods to get your job done. Have you started it, if so please provide your code and specify the exact problem please.

Comment: Right now i can achieve this functionality by the use of this autocomplete pakage https://pub.dev/packages/autocomplete_textfield#-installing-tab-